# Why do certain POSIX system calls return an integer instead of a boolean?

Tags: integer, boolean, posix, semantics

In the lastest version of the **POSIX.1-2017** specification, some system calls, like `link()/unlink()`, `access()` or `chmod()` return either 0 (successful) or -1 (unsuccessful).

In that case, wouldn't it have been more semantically correct to return a **boolean** ?

And if I change the return type from `int` to `boolean`, is it still **POSIX-compliant** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has been done to have similar return type among all functions returning an integer value. Otherwise the programmer should check every time if that function is returning an `int` or a `boolean`.

Originally `bool` was not even a type in C: I don't know it was also a choice for retro-compatibility.

In some cases you don't have even choice: take as examples the following:

> `int fflush(FILE *fp)` Returns: 0 if OK, EOF on error
>
> `int fclose(FILE *fp);` Returns: 0 if OK, EOF on error
>
> `int atexit(void (*func)(void))` Returns: 0 if OK, nonzero on error

`EOF` is a macro generally defined as `-1` but it is not guaranteed. In some other cases you want to specify the error

Comment: thanks for the useful answer.

I do not see the problem to check the return type of a function in the API whenever I need it, but consistence is valuable as well. It really surprised me that `bool` was not an early part of the language, its presence seems so natural.

Comment: Your welcome and hope it helped but further research for your question should be done (if you find something useful please share here: I am curious). Please upvote the question if it was useful